# MS Access keep ID field in subform filled with ID from parent form

Tags: database, forms, vba, ms-access, ms-access-2013

Everytime I jump to where I can enter e new record, the ID field from the parent is empty and so the connection is lost. I am looking for a workaround.

### My Setup

I have a parent form that deals with two 1:n relationships

(school-class --> pupils, school-class --> tests).

For the first relationship I used the wizard. Everything works find. For the second I show the connected tests in an unbound list. Under the list is a button opening the form for entering a new record (test) for the class I came from (parent form). So I filter the sub-form via VBA so that only the tests of the current class are shown. That works perfectly fine, too.

When moving through the tests already connected with the class the correct ID (of the class filtered) is the value of the corresponding input field. But when I come to the new new record state (all fields empty), then the connection to the parent breaks and the user has to manually enter the ID of the parent (school-class).

### My Question

Is my setup correct?
Is there a better way to create a subform that offers to (only) enter a new record connected to the parent data? (Maybe without the ID input field in the subform and passing of forcing the value via VBA?)

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Default Value to set the classid of Tests form but be sure the parent form is open in background or behind the pop up.

Under Property Sheet/Data tab of Tests form's classid control, enter in Default Value cell:

```
=Forms!parentformname!classid
```

Alternatively, in [VBA](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837160.aspx) in the Tests form's OnOpen Event:

```
Me.classid.DefaultValue = Forms!parentformname!classid
```

You can then choose to hide (Visible - No) this classid control so users do not modify it. It's always advised to never allow users control of primary and foreign keys.

Comment: Oh my... This solution is so simple - it almost hurt :-)
I just set the Default Value and everything's fine.

Thank you!

Comment: Well... this solution works but now I have another problem. When somebody pushes the button, he automatically jumps to the "new record" with the parent-it being the default value. If the user now closes the form without editing, there is an almost blank record saved to the db.

Is there a smart way dealing with that? Well, when I just define some of the input parameters as required, the user gets some ugly prompts. I'd prefer that the input is just not stored. Any idea? w/ or w/o VBA?

Comment: Which version above did you use? Form control or VBA? Default values does not save until a record is saved. If all form fields remain empty when form is closed, no data will be saved. Check to see your Form Close or any Close Button event. Remove any Save Record command.